# rewrite url with domain as condition

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using apache with mod_rewrite and codeigniter to do my routing.

I've got two seperate (wildcard)domains pointing to my website, say: *.foo.com and *.bar.com

*.foo.com/somepath should to rewrite to *.foo.com/index.php/somepath

and *.bar.com.somepath should to rewrite to *.bar.com/index.php/bar/somepath

This is my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} [^.]{3}\.bar\.com [NC]
RewriteCond $1 !(index\.php|assets|favicon|bar)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/pzdossier/$1 [L] 

RewriteCond $1 !(index\.php|assets|favicon)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

This gives me the correct result when I go to dev.foo.com/whatever

but when I go to dev.bar.com/whatever it just rewrites to dev.bar.com/index.php/whatever instead of pzdossier.

If I change

```
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/pzdossier/$1 [L]
```

to

```
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/pzdossier/$1 [L,R=302]
```

It works, I get redirected to /index.php/pzdossier/whatever.

What am I doing wrong? why does a redirect work, but a rewrite doesnt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Codeigniter was using the $_SERVER['request_info'] to determine what controller to call.

When I changed that to $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] it correctly using the .htaccess rules as I wanted.

So change application/config/config.php $config['uri_protocol'] to PATH_INFO